# How does returning a function inside a function work

Tags: javascript, class, return

I feel like my example explains it well. I am unsure of how a function returning inside a function works. I feel like solving the below demo would help me understand. Any other links or documents would be nice to read though as well.

```
function LogFunction() {
  return function() {
    return "just console log this";
  };
}

console.log(LogFunction());
// "just console log this"   <<< I want this
// "[Function]"              <<< I am getting this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript functions are known as "First-class function" this means you can return / pass functions as any other type like (object / numbers). You can find [more about this here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function).

You can break this one into variables to make it more clear such as:

```
function LogFunction() {
  return function() {
    return "just console log this";
  };
}

var a = LogFunction()
console.log( a() );
```

However as others pointed correctly you can call this directly

```
console.log( LogFunction()() );
```

On the variables examples, when a `LogFunction()` is called with `()` you are invoking the function and the result of this invocation is assigned to the variable `a`, as the result of invoking the function is another function you need to call the result of the previous function in order to access the result of this function `a()`.

You can have as many levels of nested function as you wish, and with the new ES2016 you can take advantage of arrow functions to make this code much clear.

```
const LogFunction = () => () => "just console log this";
console.log( LogFunction()() );
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer man :) You win this one for explaining the most!

Answer (score 3):

You are returning the reference of the inner function, to execute it you need to put `()` again so that the function reference is executed.

```js
function LogFunction() {
  return function() {
    return "just console log this";
  };
}
console.log(LogFunction()());

//You can also get the function reference in a variable, and execute it:

const innerFunction = LogFunction(); 
//assigning the returned function reference.

console.log(innerFunction()); 
//executes the returned reference
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log((LogFunction())());
```

`LogFunction` returns a function. So `LogFubction()` **is** a function. You just call it

Answer (score 0):

Your function LogFunction returns an internal function that you also need to call to get the final result.

```js
function LogFunction() {
  return function() {
    return "just console log this";
  };
}

console.log(LogFunction()());
```

You can use less code:

```js
function LogFunction() {
  return "just console log this";
}

console.log(LogFunction())
```